# My database has some syntax errors but I can't find them, so I figured I could ask here

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

So this is my db

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `userId` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userName` varchar(55) NOT NULL, 
  `password` varchar(55) NOT NULL, 
  `firstName` varchar(55) NOT NULL, 
  `lastName` varchar(55) NOT NULL, 
   PRIMARY KEY (`userId`) ) 
INSERT INTO `users` (`userId`, `userName`, `password`, `firstName`, `lastName`) 
  VALUES (24, 'joel', '', 'Joel', 'Thomas'), (26, 'merlinsofia', '', 'merlin', 'sofia'), (27, 'matt', '', 'Matthew', 'Matthew'), (28, 'mike', '', 'Mike', 'Anto')
```

and these are all errors...

6 errors were found during analysis.

```
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "`userId`" at position 257)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "`userName`" at position 267)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "`password`" at position 279)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "`firstName`" at position 291)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "`lastName`" at position 304)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "VALUES" at position 316)
```

SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` ( 
 `userId` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
 `userName` varchar(55) NOT NULL, 
 `password` varchar(55) NOT NULL, 
 `firstName` varchar(55) NOT NULL, 
`lastName` varchar(55) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`userId`) ) 
INSERT INTO `users` (`userId`, `userName`, `password`, `firstName`, `lastName`) 
   VALUES (24, 'joel', '', 'Joel', 'Thomas'), (26, 'merlinsofia', '', 'merlin', 'sofia'), (27, 'matt', '', 'Matthew', 'Matthew'), (28, 'mike', '', 'Mike', 'Anto')
```

MySQL said: Documentation

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO `users` (`userId`, `userName`, `password`, `firstName`, `lastName`) ' at line 1
```

I cant seem to find errors, but keep in mind that I am a beginner so I wanted to ask here for help!

Comment: The question is related to `MySQL`, I had removed `SQL-Server` tag.

Comment: You haven't put `;` at the end of `create` statement. Syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create and Insert needs to be separated by `;`. That's all.

Try this :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `userId` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userName` varchar(55) NOT NULL, 
  `password` varchar(55) NOT NULL, 
  `firstName` varchar(55) NOT NULL, 
  `lastName` varchar(55) NOT NULL, 
   PRIMARY KEY (`userId`) ) ;
INSERT INTO `users` (`userId`, `userName`, `password`, `firstName`, `lastName`) 
  VALUES (24, 'joel', '', 'Joel', 'Thomas'), (26, 'merlinsofia', '', 'merlin', 'sofia'), (27, 'matt', '', 'Matthew', 'Matthew'), (28, 'mike', '', 'Mike', 'Anto')
```